# Use cookie and session in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies

When I login to a page using my credentials and leave that page without logging out, next time  I visit that same page I'm automatically logged in again.

What's the mechanics behind this and how can I implement this using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Sessions and Cookies both have their respective parts in the **[PHP Documentation](http://php.net)**.

I'll try to give you a short summery of how each works:

### Cookies

A Cookie is a file saved to the client's computer, in a key=value format, The cookie can be saved by the client in 2 ways,

1. When declared with in JavaScript code
2. When sent as a header from the server

We are interested in #2, You can use PHP to send the cookie header, and **request the client** to save the cookie (Note that the client may or may not implement this request).

On the next request, you can check for cookies that the client sent along with its HTTP request using the `$_COOKIE` superglobal.

### Sessions

A session is a set of variables (in the form of an associative array) which is saved on the server side, and is linked with a **unique session ID**. That session ID is sent to the client (usually in the form of a cookie). When the client then requests a page from the server, it sends the session ID along with the request. The server reads it, and fetches the variable associated with the ID (usually from a file or a database), and sets it into the `$_SESSION` superglobal.

---

Understanding that should help you figure out how to make the sticky login system.

Answer (score 0):

its a simple session Function only.. for Session just you refer this link

```
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php
```

if u want to use cookies.. use this concept..below

```
 <html><head><script type="text/javascript">function getCookie(c_name){var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)  {  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")); y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");  if (x==c_name)    {     return unescape(y);    }  }}function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){var exdate=new Date();exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;}function checkCookie(){var username=getCookie("username");if (username!=null && username!="")  {  alert("Welcome again " + username);  }else   {  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");  if (username!=null && username!="")    {   setCookie("username",username,365);    }  }}</script></head><body onload="checkCookie()"></body></html>
```